# Why does scrolling through QFontComboBox consume a lot of memory?

Tags: c++, qt, memory

In a text editor I'm working on in Qt 5.1.1 (MinGW) I realized that scrolling through the QFontComboBox adds about 40MB of RAM usage to the app. To test if the issue was local only to my text editor I created a bare bones application with just a QFontComboBox on a tool bar in a QMainWindow and the result is still the same. The applications starts off at 12MB and when I scroll through the list (which is also a visually jerky experience) about 40MB is added on. I decided to use Qt 5.2.1 VS2012 instead but this time almost 80MB of RAM was used up. This is the simple code all in the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    toolBar = new QToolBar;
    fontCBox = new QFontComboBox;
    toolBar->addWidget(fontCBox);

    addToolBar(toolBar);
}
```

After an hour or so the application releases some of the memory but scrolling through the list just inflates it again. Is it just me acting like a RAM miser or is this the regular behaviour for QFontComboBox? I can only think that Qt is somehow "loading" all the fonts which is causing this problem but I have no evidence of that. Has anyone come across this before and know of a solution?

Comment: How are you measuring the application's RAM usage? Be as specific as you can, including telling us what tool you are using and precisely which field you are reporting.

Comment: All of these were just observations I made from the task manager on windows 8. Is this not a viable means of just assessing how much memory is used? If not I guess I'd have to learn how to better test this since I don't have any experience with any other tools.

Comment: In order to display the font name in the font its named for the font must be loaded. Font.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I checked out what you were referring to in the resource monitor tool and this is what I got. Hope it is more helpful.

Before scrolling:
Commit - 43MB
Working Set - 22MB
Private - 12MB

After scrolling:
Commit - 100MB
Working Set - 75MB
Private - 65MB

Comment: That is real RAM usage. (The private working set.)